# Add property to AttributeSet class/database

Tags: magento-1.9, attribute-set

I'm working on an import algorithm and I have to keep different IDs to identify attribute-sets at a later time.

Is there an option to extend the class/database-object of attribute-sets? I mean not to add an attribute like length/height/weight/etc. (i.e. for products) but an additional property next to attribute-set-name, ..., . This property does not have to be visible to the backend-user.

In short: What class do I have to extend in my install script (is there even a more or less simple solution to this problem)? How do I set and get those additional properties?